# Unable to capture Ctrl+Alt+Arrow key event in jQuery hotkeys

Tags: jquery, hotkeys

Could u please tell me what was the hotkey event for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Up</kbd>. because i am trying using the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Up</kbd> event it is not working for me. Actually i am using Jquery.hotkeys plugin for the same. the following is the code:

```
jQuery(document).bind('keydown', 'ctrl+Alt+up', function() {
    console.log("ctrl+Alt+up");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot catch key events in this manner. To discover which keys are pressed you need to interrogate the Event object passed to the `keydown` handler. Try this:

```
$(document).bind('keydown', function(e) {
    if (e.ctrlKey && e.altKey && e.which == 38) {
        console.log("ctrl+Alt+up");
    }
});
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/n9cj3qj8/)

Comment: Sorry to say that it is not working for me as in if condition it is always getting false hence it will not work.

Comment: Can you show an example of your non-working code. As you can see from the fiddle example it should be working fine

Comment: I have copied ur code and pasted and tried running that but it is not giving me expected results. i.e hot keys are not working for me